# IOS Post Photo To Facebook Without The Facebook Connect-Api

Tags: iphone, ios, image, facebook

Is it possible to post a photo to a Facebook Page wall without using the Facebook connect Api?

To post some text I tried using this:

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"fb://publish/profile/1111111111112311?text=%@",@"some text here"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:post];
```

thanks

Answer (score 3):

To do this, I would suggest using Sharekit.  ShareKit is a free api that allows you to intregrate many sharing feastures for many services, with minimal code (less than 20 lines).

Here is a link to get ShareKit: [getsharekit.com](http://getsharekit.com)

To share a photo on Facebook with Sharekit, do this:

1. Add sharekit to your project by coping the files found at the link above
2. Use the following code to set up the share instance:

   ```
   UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"someImage.jpg"];
   SHKItem *item = [SHKItem image:image title:@"Look at this picture!"];
   ```
3. Then just share the image with this:

   ```
   [SHKFacebook shareItem:item];
   ```

However, the newest Facebook API is actually pretty easy to use.  And it's very well documented, so you might want to check it out.  There are some benefits to using Facebook's actually API, rather then use a proxy service.

Comment: If you use ShareKit, don't forget to include a copy of it's license agreement somewhere in your app (perhaps an about screen), or else you are committing copyright infringement (you definitely don't want to do that, especially in a popular app).

Comment: True, and I completely agree, but without cracking the app, would anyone really be able to tell

Comment: sharekit does not post a photo to Facebook page wall. It creates a photo album for your app and upload the photo. You can only specify the image and the caption. No link, description, title, etc.